# nesting object within another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have an array and an object.

```
var myObj = { "abc": 200, "xyz": 300};
vay myArray = ["one", "two"]
```

i want to next the values of myObj inside "one".

so myArray[0] would return object data-

the console.log(myArray) would look something like.

```
-"one"
    *Object
            *abc:200
            *xyz:300
-"two"
```

i tried using push to add myObj to myArray[0], but it did not work.
Any suggestions.

**Update:**
My code looks like this now, maybe this will help me ask correctly:

```
var allData = {
user1:[userData]}
```

this runs each time a function is called.

userData the first time is ex: `{name:bob, id:123}` and `{name:dave, id:456}` the second time the function runs.

but if i do a `console.log{allData)`, i only see the last `userDat` objecta. i would like it to add on to the user1 each time i use the function so that i could essentially do the following `allData.user1[1].name;` and get "dave"

Comment: Your request is impossible, because it doesn't really make sense. You're getting mixed up between keys and values: Objects have keys (or indices) and corresponding values. Arrays are exactly the same, where elements (i.e. values) are simply indexed by an *integer*-like key. So in your original example `"one"` is a value, but then you want it to be a key. As such, your requirements don't make sense.

Comment: added more details to my question to see if that helps. i dont know if that makes anything clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following structure is what you seem to be asking for:

```
var myArray = [
                { "one" : { "abc": 200, "xyz": 300} },
                "two"
              ];
```

That is, the first element in the array becomes an object that has one property named "one", and the property references the object `{ "abc": 200, "xyz": 300}`. The second element in the array is still just a string, "two".

To access the "abc" property you'd say `myArray[0]["one"]["abc"]` or `myArray[0].one.abc`. This seems kind of clunky and perhaps isn't at all what you want, but as I said it's what you seem to be asking for.

If the object and array both already exist as shown in your question and you want to use the current value of array element 0 to be the key in the object you can do this:

```
var myObj = { "abc": 200, "xyz": 300},
    myArray = ["one", "two"];

var tempObj = {};
tempObj[myArray[0]] = myObj;
myArray[0] = tempObj;
```

It seems to me that a more sensible structure would be:

```
var myObj = {
       "one" : { "abc": 200, "xyz": 300 },
       "two" : null
};
```

So that you can simply say `myObj["one"]["abc"]` or `myObj.one.abc`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want it a generic approach(not with any hardcoded values), in which case try this:

```
    var myObj = { "abc": 200, "xyz": 300}; 
    var myArray = ["one", "two"];
    var one = myArray[0];
    var temp = {};
    temp[one] = myObj;
    myArray[0] = temp;
    console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

[{
    "abc": 200,
    "xyz": 300
    },
"two"]
or
[{  "one":{
        "abc": 200,
        "xyz": 300
    }},
    "two"]
your 
myArray[0] is a String, which not have a push method